# Should I get vaccination before travelling to Lombok (Indonesia)

Tags: health, indonesia, lombok

Im gonna go to Lombok in december. Would like to know if need to get vaccination against malaria or other diseases.

Comment: As ever, the best answer for this is: A: Your country's public health body (they know what vaccinations you will already have) and B: A medical professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as @Cmaster hints at in his comment, no vaccine for malaria exists.

The best ways to prevent malaria is taking [anti malarial medicine](http://www.webmd.com/a-to-z-guides/tc/malaria-prevention#1) and by avoiding mosquito bites.

According to the [British National Health Service](http://www.fitfortravel.nhs.uk/destinations/asia-(east)/indonesia/indonesia-malaria-map.aspx), the malaria risk in Indonesia varies from area to area. Lombok has apparently been deemed "low risk" for malaria. It might be better to consult with a doctor who specializes in travel medicine.

Answer (score 3):

The CDC recommends the following vaccinations for travel to Indonesia:

(From: http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/destinations/traveler/none/indonesia )

For everyone:

Hepatitis A
 Typhoid

Some travelers (visit link on top to see if you are one of the travelers who it's recommended for):

Hepatitis B, Japanese Encephalitis, Malaria, Rabies

Also Indonesia requires proof of yellow fever vaccination if you're traveling from a yellow fever 'risk country', the list of countries is here: http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/yellowbook/2016/infectious-diseases-related-to-travel/yellow-fever#4728

Answer (score 2):

### Go to a travel clinic

There should be a travel clinic specializing in this somewhere near you. They will take into account your medical background, current vaccinations and know which diseases are a problem where you are going.